# Maximum call stack size exceeded in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am loading data from SQL table using AngularJS and web API. I made a function that shows values in input texts when a row is selected from HTML table. I got this error when i click on any row on the html table when debug.

The HTML

```
<td>Code</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="10" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" title="Alphnumeric" required autofocus ng-model="selectedMember.Code.Staff_Type_Code">
                    <input type="text" size="10" hidden ng-model="selectedMember.sys_key" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Latin Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" required size="35" ng-model="selectedMember.Latin.L_Desc"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Local Description</td>
                <td><input type="text" required size="35" ng-model="selectedMember.Local.A_Desc"></td>
            </tr>


 <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="c in Contracts | filter:selectedMember.Code | filter:selectedMember.Latin | filter:selectedMember.Local ">

                <td style="display:none;"><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.sys_key}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Staff_Type_Code}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.L_Desc}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.A_Desc}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Hours_Day}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Days_Week}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Type_EndWork}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="#" ng-click="showInEdit(c)">{{c.Num_EndWork}}</a></td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Controller.js

```
 $scope.selectedMember = {  Code: "",sys_key:"", Latin:"" , Local:"", Hours_Day :"", Days_Week:"", Num_EndWork:""  } 

$scope.showInEdit = function (member)
{
    debugger;
    $scope.selectedMember = member;
    $scope.selectedMember.Code = member;
    $scope.selectedMember.Latin = member;
    $scope.selectedMember.Local = member;

}
```

when I comment the last 3 lines, selected row values are not displayed in input texts. or i must cancel the filter. is there is a way to work both both
Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: are you passing the whole object in `showInEdit()` function?? And if so `$scope.selectedMember = member;` and `$scope.selectedMember.Code = member;` looks like contradictory. I think you should comment the first line
`$scope.selectedMember = member;` and can you share data of your `Contracts` array?

Comment: Thanks for replying, But when i comment  $scope.selectedMember = member; Some input texts data will be empty. Actually it is not an array , i bring data from sql db

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes get this if you accidentally import/embed the same JS file twice, worth checking in your resources tab of the inspector . or if you are calling a function which is calling another function and so forth .

Comment: i checked the top of the code and didnt found that the JS file is not repeated, any idea , thanks for replying

Comment: when I comment the last 3 lines in controller, selected row values are not displayed in input texts. or i must cancel the filter. is there is a way to work both both Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance

Comment: any help or idea

Comment: is it coming as Range Error ? Can you copy and paste your error from console.

Comment: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at deepCompare (angular.js:21022)    thanks for replying

Comment: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at deepCompare (http://localhost/ContractTypesUI/Scripts/angular.js:21022:21)

Comment: you comment last 3 lines ? which lines ? then the error does not come?

Comment: the last three lines in controller started by $scope.selectedMember.Code = member;

Comment: ok ! so then you are not getting error ?  i think your member is an object  and when you are assigning it to $scope.selectedMember.Latin = member , its causing problem.   Can you not assign and try assigning from member's value like $scope.selectedMember.code = member.code or something ?

Comment: Also it does not make any sense that you are assigning entire object to selectedmember as  $scope.selectedMember = member and then you are assigning individually also  like  $scope.selectedMember.Code = member; . This will replace your $scope.selectedMember at first line itself . now your $scope.selectedMember and member is just the same .

Comment: do you mean like this  $scope.selectedMember = member.Code;              when i did this nothing appears in all input text when click on html table row

Comment: it is the only way till now to show all html row data in input texts, when i remove  $scope.selectedMember.Code = member , the code input text data disappears

Comment: OR remove the filter in the ng-repeat, the error disappears

Comment: i edited in the html to show you how i call filter and selectedMemeber